# Running Time of Randomized Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

Consider the following silly randomized variant of binary search. You are given a sorted array
A of n integers and the integer v that you are searching for is chosen uniformly at random from A.
Then, instead of comparing v with the value in the middle of the array, the randomized binary search
variant chooses a random number r from 1 to n and it compares v with A[r]. Depending on whether
v is larger or smaller, this process is repeated recursively on the left sub-array or the right sub-array,
until the location of v is found. Prove a tight bound on the expected running time of this algorithm.

Here is what I got for the T(n)

`T(n) = T(n-r) + T(r) + Θ(1)`

However, I have no clue how to get a tight bound.

Comment: The worst case is O(n) if the random number generator happens to always choose 1 or n.

Comment: @MarkRansom ...which happens with probability 2/factorial(n).  In other words, no noticeable impact on computation time for tiny values of n, far less likely than being struck by a meteorite for n > 10, and "ain't never gonna happen in this universe" for n > 20.

Comment: @pjs I was speaking about worst case in a mathematical sense, probabilities be damned. That's a lot different than a practical discussion. Since the question was about a "tight bound" I thought it might have some bearing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Since the question was about "a tight bound on the **expected** running time," focusing on the worst case has no bearing.  Expected value is a probabilistic concept, and weights outcomes with their probability of occurring.  Your worst case has virtually no impact on run time where it has noticeable probability of occurring, and in expectation converges very rapidly towards zero impact.

Comment: Oops, make that probability (2^n)/factorial(n).  It still converges to zero amazingly fast, e.g., 4.3E-13 for n = 20, 4E-24 for n = 30.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation of T(n) is not completely correct. Actually,

Lets try to look over all the cases. When we reduce the problem size by partitioning the array across any random point, the reduced sub-problem will have any size from 1 to n with uniform probability. Hence with probability 1/n, search space becomes r. So expected running time becomes

`T(n) = sum ( T(r)*Pr(search space becomes r) ) + O(1) = sum ( T(r) )/n + O(1)`

Which gives,

`T(n) = average(T(r)) + O(1)`

Let expected time complexity of random binary sort be T(n).

```
T(n) = [ T(1)+T(2)+...+T(n)]/n + 1
n*T(n) = T(1)+T(2)+...+T(n) + n
(n-1)*T(n-1) = T(1)+T(2)+...+T(n-1) + n-1       [substituiting n by n-1]
n*T(n) - (n-1)*T(n-1) = T(n) + 1
(n-1)*T(n) - (n-1)*T(n-1) =  1
(n-1)*T(n) = (n-1)*T(n-1) + 1
T(n) = 1/(n-1) + T(n-1)
T(n) = 1/(n-1) + 1/(n-2) + T(n-2)               [ T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1/(n-2) ]
...
T(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(n-1) = H(n-1) < H(n) = O(log n) 
[ H(n) = reciprocal sum of first n natural numbers   ]
```

so, `T(n) = O(log n)`

[Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

[bound of H(n)](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/67e2780ee0fc221b88fea2f3236053cab3d83f15)

Comment: Can you explain how you get T(n) = average(T(r) + 0(1))?